# jQuery AJAX passing more than one variable to data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

below you can see the html code, javascript/jquery and PHP. I'm trying to send a request using AJAX PHP, to send multiple variable to PHP, one of them is FormData and the other is some text or values from inputs etc.

Here's html code:

```
<div>
<p>Name:</p>
<input id="newP_name"></input>
<p>Product Image</p>
<input type="file" id="img"></input>
<p>Description:</p>
<textarea id="newP_desc"></textarea>
<button name="submitProductBtn" id="submitProductBtn">Submit</button>
```

Here's my javascript:

```
$("#submitProductBtn").click(function(){

        var file_data = $('#img').prop('files')[0];
        var form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append('file', file_data);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'imgParser.php',
            dataType: 'text',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: form_data, name: "John",
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert("ERROR OCCURED");
            }
        });
    });
```

As you can see I'm trying to pass to 'data:' the FormData (image) and a second variable name.

Here's PHP code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES["file"]["name"])){
    if($_FILES["file"]["error"] == 0){
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "images/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        echo $_POST["name"];
    }else{
        echo $_POST["name"];
    }
}
?>
```

I would expect it to print "John", but the alert is blank, image showing ->

[image]

Any help appreciated,
thanks in advance.

***EDIT:***

Changed slightly the jQuery code, still outputs empty, but when I had code commented out in PHP (below closing tag), it printed it.

here's my new jquery code:

```
$("#submitProductBtn").click(function(){

        var file_data = $('#img').prop('files')[0];
        var form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append('file', file_data);
        form_data.append('name', "John");

        $.ajax({
            url: 'imgParser.php',
            dataType: 'text',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: form_data,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert("ERROR OCCURED");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Is that HTML you posted in a form?

Comment: Please, [quit using `alert()` for troubleshooting.](http://stravid.com/en/stop-the-javascript-alert-madness/), use `console.log()` instead.

Comment: @Musa No html is not in a form its is as it it shown and nothing else is wrapped around that div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You append all data fields to the form data object just like you did with the file

```
form_data.append('file', file_data);
form_data.append('name', 'John');
```

Comment: what's happening? I deleted my answer and upvoted you. Why this strange ...... Sorry if you have any idea could you share it? Thanks

Comment: I guess someone is on a down voting spree

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work, maybe there's something else I'm missing? Or there's a different way of doing it

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what is `form_data` maybe you can try this,

```
form_data.append('file', file_data);
form_data.append('name', 'john');
```

and simply pass `form_data` in `data` property

```
 $.ajax({
     ...
     ...
     data: form_data
```